# In the context of a video lecture/vodcast/... how to translate "I would like to talk to you about ..."

Tags: translation

In the context of a video lecture/vodcast/... how to translate the English sentence "(In this video) **I would like to talk to you about** ..." this or that topic ... into Mandarin?

Please use traditional Chinese characters in your answer.

Comment: 我想告訴你（有）關於....... or 我想和你談談（有）關於......

Comment: http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=would+like+to+talk+about   http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-simptrad.html

Comment: I'd say something like 這一次我想跟你們講。。。

Comment: @Philipp please note I would like to concisely state the topic (5 characters, two words in English equivalent) after the sentence. In that case, perhaps 談 is perhaps more appropriate?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen sorry, what is the exact English sentence you want to say in Chinese? In my example, you'd just add the topic (or topics) after the dots.

Comment: @Philipp Let's say for example. *In this video I would like to talk to you about beef noodles.* I am not so sure whether just putting *牛肉麵* where your tree dots are sounds so harmonious.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen 這一次，我想跟你們講牛肉面 would be absolutely acceptable. You can further “colloquialize” it by adding 這個話題 after 牛肉面, if that sounds more natural to you, or you could say 我今天想跟你們講的話題就是牛肉面。

Comment: @Phillipp Thank you very much for these multiple options. So you prefer 講 over 談? Why not user-487's solution using 關於?

Answer (score 4):

I think the audience you would target is important.

To the people from mainland, I suggest putting this like "在這裡，我要和大家聊一下（關於）..." or "在這裡，我們要聊的話題是...". Using 我們 is a good choice because the audience may feel you were with them. 大家 and 聊 can pull you closer to your audience on the topic, as if you were chatting, instead of teaching. If you want to talk about 牛肉麵, you could say "在這裡，我要和大家聊的話題是'牛肉麵'" or "在這裡，我們要聊的話題是'牛肉麵'" .

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

我想通過這個視頻告訴你們 ...